# average time-distance between grouped events

Tags: r

df is battle events within years & conflicts. I am trying to calculate the average distance (in time) between battles within conflict years.

Header looks something like this:

```
conflictId | year | event_date | event_type
107          1997   1997-01-01   1
107          1997   1997-01-01   1
20           1997   1997-01-01   1
20           1997   1997-01-01   2
20           1997   1997-01-03   1
```

what I first tried was

`time_prev_total <- aggregate (event_date ~ conflictId + year, data, diff)`

but I end up with `event_date` being a list in the new df. Attempts to extract the first index position of the list within the df have been unsuccessful.

Alternatively it was suggested to me that I could create a time index within each conflict year, then lag that index, create a new data frame with `conflictId`, `year`, `event_date`, and the lagged index, and then merge that with the original df, but match the lagged index in the new df with the old index in the original df. I have tried to implement this but am a little unsure how to index the obs. within conflict years since it is unbalanced.

Comment: without reproducible data it's very difficult to know where the problem is occurring.  Please provide a small sample of data.  This does two things: 1) It makes helping you easier  2) makes your question more usable by other future searchers

Comment: yea sorry about that, I can't seem to get tab to work so I can format it in an appropriate way. I assume I am making some type of newbie error here.

Comment: that's ok.  You can select just some rows using indexing: `x <- dat[c(1,2,3,10,11,12),]` and then use `dput(x)` to provide us with reproducible data.  If you need more help with that open another thread and ask because providing reproducible data is going to get you target results.

Comment: This is what you were looking for essentially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ddply` to split a data.frame into pieces
(one per year and conflict) and apply a function to each.

```
# Sample data
n <- 100
d <- data.frame(
  conflictId = sample(1:3,       n, replace=TRUE),
  year       = sample(1990:2000, n, replace=TRUE),
  event_date = sample(0:364,     n, replace=TRUE),
  event_type = sample(1:10,      n, replace=TRUE)
)
d$event_date <- as.Date(ISOdate(d$year,1,1)) + d$event_date
library(plyr)

# Average distance between battles, within each year and conflict
ddply(
  d, 
  c("year","conflictId"), 
  summarize,
  average = mean(dist(event_date))
)

# Average distance between consecutive battles, within each year and conflict
d <- d[order(d$event_date),]
ddply(
  d, 
  c("year","conflictId"), 
  summarize,
  average = mean(diff(event_date))
)
```